# How can i get dependency pairs identified by the CCG parser without C&C tool

Tags: java, parsing, nlp

I'm looking for an existing library (java) or solve my problem ,
my problem is i want get dependency pairs identified by the CCG parser for a question ,
i try  [C&C](http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc/wiki/Demo) tools ( c++ and python ,no one for java ).

example :

Q:How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia?

after parse

```
Parse
(ROOT
  (SBARQ
    (WHADVP (WRB How))
    (SQ (VBD did)
      (NP (NN serfdom))
      (VP
        (VP (VB develop)
          (PRT (RP in)))
        (CC and)
        (VP
          (ADVP (RB then))
          (VB leave)
          (NP (NNP Russia)))))))
```

this is code i use to get this parse (I read this [tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/opennlp-tutorial/#parser) ):

```
public static void Parse() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("lib\\opennlp-tools-1.5.0\\en-parser-chunking.zip");

    ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);

    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);

    String sentence = "What does the Peugeot company manufacture";
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, 1);

    for (Parse p : topParses)
        p.show();

    is.close();
}
```

i need make result parse to graph like picture below
[image]

Comment: Google found this:  http://openccg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes i know it but this lib work with XML file and it take a lot of time , i work on document i need make sure that is work fast as i can , thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Adel Would you rather have a working slow solution or no solution at all?

Comment: @Adel, you can try a different approach with `Head-drive Phrase Structure Grammar` (HPSG) which is even harder to setup but it works really well in parsing English. www.moin.delph-in.net/